# Laravel VueJS Put. Patch and Delete request 403, permission denied

Tags: laravel, apache, vue.js, patch

I have developed a management web application with Laravel 7. I use VueJS as the apps' frontend. I have hosted the application in my own VPS, that's running Cent OS with CWP. I get 403 on a PATCH, PUT or DELETE request. Both GET and POST work without any issue. Here's a screenshot of what I get in the chrome dev tools. I have generated a key, cleared cache, config, and routes but nothing worked so far. I have the .htaccess file in the public root.

[403 Error on Put, Patch, and Delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htWB7.png)

My .htaccess

> Blockquote
>
>
> Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !(pwa|api) [NC]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

The application root is one level up from the public root, in a folder called system. I did encounter another problem when I create a link with "ln -s" the storage folder contents also get 403. I didn't use "storage:link" to link the storage files to the public directory, as it makes a public folder in the application root, not in the public root.

Screenshot of the document root.

[Document Root Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWXsO.png)

Comment: I switched to Nginx, and issue as resolved. The will only happen with Apache, I think.

Answer (score 0):

in laravel if you want to use `PATCH` or any other method except `GET` and `POST` you should change method to `POST` and then send method inside a parameter that name is `_method` and value is what you want for example:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: your_url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                _method: 'PATCH'
            },
            success: function (data) {
              // success
            },
            error: function () {
              // error
            }
        });
```

this means `PATCH` method for laravel not `POST`